# How to get the script path of a python process who's cmdline is ["python"], with no path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, shebang, psutil

I'm trying to get and kill all other running python instances of the same script, I found an edge case where the path is not in [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/)'s [`cmdline`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cmdline) list, when the process is started with `./myscript.py` and not `python ./myscript.py`

the script's content is, note the shebang:

```
#!/bin/python
import os
import psutil
import sys
import time

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if "python" in proc.name():
        print("name", proc.name())
        script_path = sys.argv[0]
        proc_script_path = sys.argv[0]
        if len(proc.cmdline()) > 1:
            proc_script_path = proc.cmdline()[1]
        else: 
            print("there's no path in cmdline")
        if script_path.startswith("." + os.sep) or script_path.startswith(".." + os.sep):
            script_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), script_path))
        if proc_script_path.startswith("." + os.sep) or proc_script_path.startswith(".." + os.sep):
            proc_script_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(proc.cwd(), proc_script_path))
        print("script_path", script_path)
        print("proc_script_path", proc_script_path)
        print("my pid", os.getpid())
        print("other pid", proc.pid)
        if  script_path == proc_script_path and os.getpid() != proc.pid:
            print("terminating instance ", proc.pid)
            proc.kill()

time.sleep(300)
```

how can I get the script path of a python process when it's not in [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/)'s [`cmdline`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cmdline)?

Answer (score 2):

When invoking a python script like this, the check `if 'python' in proc.name()` is the problem. This will not show python or python3 for the scripts in question, but it will show the script name. Try the following:

```py
import psutil

for proc in proc.process_iter():
    print('Script name: {}, cmdline: {}'.format(proc.name(), proc.cmdline()))
```

You should see something like ():
`Script name: myscript.py, cmdline: ['/usr/bin/python3', './myscript.py']`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I want to get the script path from a psutil process instance.

Comment: you're right, just found that out, and wrote and posted an answer at the same time as you edited yours.

Answer (score 1):

when the process is started with `./relative/or/absolute/path/to/script.py` and not `python /relative/or/absolute/path/to/script.py`
the `psutil.Process.name()` is `script.py` and not `python`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of process paths running your `script.py`:

```
    ps -eo pid,args|awk '/script.py/ && $2 != "awk" {print}'
```

To get get the list of process paths running your script.py not having psutil in the path. Replace your `script.py` and `psutil` in the following script.

```
    ps -eo pid,args|awk '! /psutil/ && /script.py/ && $2 != "awk" {print}'
```

#### explanation:

`ps -eo pid,args` list all processes, providing process id and process path (args)

`! /psutil/` match all process paths **not** having psutil in the path.

`&& /script.py/` and match all process paths having script.py in the path.

`&& $2 != "awk"` and not wanting this awk process.

`{print}` output the matched lines.

Comment: I rejected your question edit which added awk tag and removed the shebang tag because this question is more about python and psutil (and not shell script), a _cross-platform_ library for process and system monitoring, the ps and awk commands are unix-specific. the shebang tag is relevant because without it you can't run a script only with it's path.