# is the behavior of sys.argv[0] the same on windows when running script only with a path >like_so.py?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, command-line-arguments, file-association

on Windows it's possible to run a python script >`like_so.py`, with the help of the Python launcher for Windows and file associations.

here's two line python script, `like_so.py`:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

on unix when running it $`./like_so.py` from the terminal, the output is `./like_so.py`

is the behavior consistent on Windows?

when running it on Windows >`like_so.py` is the output `like_so.py`?

Comment: No, the command line template is `py.exe "%1" %*`, where `%1` gets replaced by the fully-qualified path of the target file and `%*` contains any command-line arguments.

Comment: thanks, why not an answer though? is it not really a programming question? should I delete it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reason it matters? Or is this just a question for its own sake?

Comment: should I remove the last sentence from my previous question, because it's unix specific? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55555882/how-to-get-the-script-path-of-a-python-process-whos-cmdline-is-python-with

Comment: looks like I should, because the issue concerning that question is unix-specific, because on windows a process's commandline is never <path-to-script>.py, right?

Comment: If run directly, the commandline can be `"<path/to/>python<.exe>" "<path/to/>script.py"`. But if run via the file association -- given the default configuration for the py launcher -- it will always be fully-qualified for both the executable and the script, i.e. `"path/to/python.exe" "path/to/script.py"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191387/discussion-between-wis-and-eryksun).